# Unity assembly lookup

Tags: c#, unity-container

Having a slight issue with unity (unity 3.xx and Unity.WebAPI 5.1) all works fine with my config file but I need to have the interface dlls and concrete dlls location in separate folders.

The interface dlls will be located in the application's bin folder, but the location of the concretes maybe anywhere on the server. Therefore I need to specify an absolute path (or paths) for the location of these concretes. They cannot be in the GAC for other reasons.

Is this possible with unity or do I get my boss to let me develop this as a service based solution.

Thanks

Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have used is as follows:

Add a custom Resolve Event Handler to the AppDomains.AsselyResolve

Inside the handler construct the path of the assembly that has failed to be loaded using the ResolveEventArgs and the absolute path name in the config file. The using Assembly.LoadFrom to load it. This way I can place assemblies anywhere I want to on the machine.

This way I can let unity do what it needs to do and when it can't find an assembly in the solutions bin folder let it throw and exception and deal with it.

It works and solved the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the [registration by convention](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/03/12/unity-configuration-registration-by-convention.aspx) feature of Unity 3.  The first parameter to the new extension method this created is an enumerable of types.

Unity 3 also added a static helper class [AllClasses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.allclasses_members.aspx) for looking up types.  The [FromAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.allclasses.fromassemblies.aspx) method on that helper would be particularly interesting for your case.

So you would still need to solve the problem of finding the actual assemblies on disk and load them, but then it's pretty easy to register the types.